# Webstorm don't recognize node.js third party modules

Tags: node.js, autocomplete, webstorm

I tried in both Webstorm 6 and 7 EAP,

Auto-completion works fine but something strange happened,

```
var SyParams = require('../params');
....
SyParams.kioskParams ( IDE gives warning, 'unresolved variable kioskParams' )
```

If I write 'require' like this;

```
var SyParams = new require('../params');
```

Everything looks good, is there a solution for that ?

Comment: The warning isn't an issue with the code (using `new` in this case probably would be). The IDE is just trying to be helpful in finding possible issues, but is blind as to what `SyParams` is and what properties it has. WebStorm's [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html#node.js) references [this blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/11/webstorm-your-node-app/) for configuring WebStorm to interact with Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `'..\params'` module is exporting a constructor function that constructs an object which has `kioskParams` as an attribute. And the constructor itself doesn't have an attribute called `kioskParams`.
It can be easier understood if you write it like this:

```
var SyParams = require('../params'); // The module exports a constructor
...

var syParams = new SyParams(); // You construct the actual object
syParams.kioskParams; //Then you access its members
```